# Using Qt ARM prebuilt binaries to cross-compile

Tags: c++, qt, arm, qt-creator, cross-compiling

I have a small ARM board with Arch Linux ARM distro. There are ARM Qt 5.5.0 binaries available in the repositories.

I want to cross-compile a program using Qt for that board on my Ubuntu Trusty x86_64 virtual machine. Do I need to cross-compile Qt from source first or there is a way to reuse prebuilt ARM binaries?

I mean, when I try to set a Qt kit in Qt Creator, it wants me to point to qmake executable. And ARM executable isn't, well, *executable* on my build machine. So it seems I need to build Qt in order to get qmake. But then it comes with its own set of libraries and I'm not sure I can replace them.

Comment: Don't know about Arch Linux. Perhaps you're better off with Debian and [multi-arch](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/jessie/sect.manipulating-packages-with-dpkg.html#sect.multi-arch) support:

Comment: @yegorich Do you mean I need to install Debian on ARM computer **and** on my build machine, then enable multi-arch to use prebuilt ARM binaries from repository on my build machine?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at this [project](https://github.com/visionsystemsgmbh/vsdebootstrap). It describes debootstrap method, i.e. the way to create a basic Debian root file system.

Comment: Another approach would be to take [Buildroot](http://buildroot.org/). It takes more time to create your root file system, but you're much more flexible in altering it and you are independent in host Linux distribution, i.e. you can keep Arch Linux. It also integrates bootloader, kernel and your own software building.

Comment: For completeness take a look at this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22255466/angstrom-archlinux-yocto-buildroot-choose-os-for-embeded-x86/22267616#22267616) too.

Comment: There should be spec file in the ARM Qt 5.5.0 that you can point an x86 *qmake* to.  Checkout the [advanced usage](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-advanced-usage.html) as you may have a different compiler name on the host as opposed to the target.  You need to a cross gcc to match the target floating point.  Your Ubuntu has several ARM cross compilers, so it should be easy to find a match for the target.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how much memory you have on your ARM board you could consider to compile directly on your board. You then have to install the dev package of Qt.

On the Orange Pi One board I can even run Qt Creator directly on the board. On smaller boards which don't have a HDMI output I run a VNC server and use the Qt Creator running on the board by a window on my host computer which is connected to the board over Wifi.

On even smaller boards I usually create my own image using buildroot which is very comfortable and supports development and cross-compilation using Qt Creator on the host machine.

Hope this helps.